# Configuring email software to receive and send SMS

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap, text-formatting, sms

I don't have a cell phone but have a cellular modem (Rocket Stick by Sierra Wireless) that has SMS sending and receiving capability. It has its own cell number. I am trying to configure Thunderbird email client to perform this task using the cell modem's number.

```
    10digitphonenumber@sms.rogers.com
```

Thunderbird is asking me for IMAP and SMTP port numbers, security, etc.  It has been annoying task trying to research this information. The only thing I was able to find out was the text format has to be ASCII.

Thunderbird 91.0 32 Bit

Do anyone know the ports Rogers SMS gateway?

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbird won't do that. It's an email client app, not an SMS app.

The Rogers email address works in the completely opposite direction – it's not a "real" email inbox that you could access via IMAP & SMTP; its purpose is so that *other* people could send emails to your address, and you would receive them converted to received SMS messages on your cell phone/modem, so your device wouldn't even know it was an email originally.

So when someone else sends an ASCII email to your `<number>@sms.rogers.com` address, it arrives as an SMS and you have to extract it from the cell modem using an SMS app (not an email app). I don't know of any "generic" apps (long ago I used to use MyPhoneExplorer but it was specific for Sony-Ericsson phones). What they all have in common is the `AT+CMGR` modem command being used to retrieve messages, which might help in your search.

(There are plenty of generic apps for *sending* SMS messages, but it seems they're all made for the purpose spamming of thousands of recipients, so they don't allow accessing received messages.)

For Linux, modem-manager-gui allows sending and reading SMS messages stored by modems.

---

(And if you *did* find an SMTP-to-SMS gateway that lets *you* send emails that get converted to SMS messages, then it would be completely unrelated to your cellular modem – literally the whole point of using such an SMTP-to-SMS gateway is so that you wouldn't *need* a phone/modem for accessing the SMS network...)